# When enable debugger in react native, no compnent work (TextInput)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging

When I run my app, after loading app, when i enable debugger then debugger open successfully, but for textinput not open keyboard, and for button not click.

If anyone facing this type of issue, please share your view,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had Same Issue while using RN 0.62.2, i couldn't find the cause of the problem but for now i have downgraded back to RN 0.61.5 and debugger works fine.